# php session: page still accessible after logging out

Tags: php, session, pdo

I am trying to build a php session login system. At the moment , I am getting some problems.  the dashboard page (after successful login) does to show the session username, also the dashboard page remains accessible, even after logging out. here is my code

**login.php**

```
session_start();
    include('dbconfig.php');
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            header('Location:dashboard.php');
        }

 if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];
            if(empty($username)){
                echo "Required field: You must enter username";
            }elseif(empty($password)){
                echo "Required field: You must enter password";
            }else{
           
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username=:username AND password=:password" );
            $stmt->bindParam('username',$username);
            $stmt->bindParam('password',$password);
                $stmt->execute();
                $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              
                    if($row>0){
                        $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["username"];
                          
                        header('Location:dashboard.php');
                        
                    }else{
                         echo "Username or Password does not match";
                    }
            }
        }
```

**dashboard.php**

```
 <?php     
        session_start();
       include('dbconfig.php');
        if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) ){
            header('Location:login.php');
        }
    ?>    

 <h5 class="text-white"><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></h5>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php  
    session_start();
   session_unset();
    session_destroy();
     header('Location:login.php');
```

Comment: Put a `die();` after every `header('Location: login.php');`  And a space after `Location:`, I think that will solve the problem

Comment: @Daantje thanks for your help. unfortunately it did not work. I ended up getting a blank dashborad page.

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting turned on?

Comment: What is the content of `dbconfig.php` ?

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: @Rain dbconfig.php holds the connection data

Answer (score -2):

You have to add a semicolon to your code :

```
<h5 class="text-white"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h5>
```

Comment: thanks but it didnt make any difference @robin

Comment: Why would they need a semicolon there? There's already `?>` which is the same thing